# apply color to every element each time using for loop

Tags: javascript

I want that blue color apply to each line after 500ms. I am new to JavaScript I tried everything but nothing work..

here is the code:

```js
let para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (let index = 0; index < para.length; index++) {
  function timer() {
    para[index].classList.toggle("blue");
  }
  setInterval(timer, 500);
}
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, ratione.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, ratione.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, ratione.
</p>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, ratione.
</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Comment: Your code seems to work as it is. Please define "_nothing work_".

Comment: Not clear on the ask here. From the code above, it looks like it is applying your color every 500ms. If you want to do it only once, you can change the `toggle` to `add` and `setInterval` to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will toggle the blue on every element every 500ms...

You want something like this:

```js
let i = 0, els = document.querySelectorAll('p');
//the selector is the same but looks better and is more readable.

setInterval(() => {
    els[i++ % els.length].classList.toggle('blue');
}, 500);
```

Comment: yes but it stop after first loop i want infinite loop

Comment: @IMRANH I've updated it to use `i++ % els.length` which should be infinite

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
para[index].classList.add("blue");
```

Comment: This does not do what the OP wants.

Comment: The difference is that Milner's answer will toggle the class on all the elements every 500 ms while mine will progressively add the class every 500ms, line-by-line.

Comment: @Dr-Vortex i want the loop to continue but your code stop after one loop on all